# Trouble with terminating a <apex:pageBlockSection>

Tags: visualforce, error

I'm having a small problem with creating a visualforce page where I'm getting an error thrown and can't figure out where the problem is. I figure that it might help by just getting another set of eyes looking at my code since I haven't been able to figure it out for the past hour and a half. Here's my code:

```
<apex:page standardController="OrderItem" sidebar="false">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Edit Order Product" subtitle="{!orderItem.Product2}"/>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Order Product" id="thePageBlock" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageMessages/>   
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" />
        <apex:actionRegion>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Product Name" columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!orderItem.Product_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Supplier ID"/>
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!orderItem.Supplier_Id__c}">
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="thePageBlock" status="status"/>
                        </apex:inputField>
                        <apex:actionStatus startText="applying value..." id="status"/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex.pageBlockSection>
        </apex:actionRegion>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: OrderItemEnterIdsButtonController line 20, column 19: The element type "apex:pageblocksection" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</apex:pageblocksection>"
```

I'm sure the mistake is obvious for some of you (it probably is and I just can't tell), but I can't seem to find the problem no matter how I look at it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your lines (near the end) says `</apex.pageBlockSection>` instead of `</apex:pageBlockSection>`

Comment: I know, I don't know what the error is talking about because those are both exactly the same thing.

Comment: No, yours has a period but should have a colon

Comment: RenegadeCoder is right. There is a dot "." instead of a colon ":" in </apex.pageBlockSection>

Comment: Oh my gosh. I guess I need to take a break from working for a while because I stared at both of those and couldn't find how they were different haha. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you should probably get some fresh air haha